# Passing multiple parameters in HTTP POST request

Tags: swift, nsurlconnection, swift2, nsurlrequest, alamofire

I am a beginner at this and I am really stuck. I want to upload a product by sending a POST request to the mentioned URL with an autogenerated client ID and product JSON sent as parameters. Plus I also want cookies in this request. I am finding this incredibly difficult to achieve with Alamofire, hence an NSURLConnection solution is equally welcome. Please help. Thanks in advance!

```
HTTP POST Request URL: http://blahblah.com/api/v1/products/saveDraft

HTTP Request Headers:
version: 0.1.7
Cookie: client=iOS; version=0.1.7; sellerId=SEL5483318784; key=178a0506-0639-4659-9495-67e5dffa42de
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 1431

HTTP URL parameters: clientId=1444657827384-344b7992-8608-49b1-976a-f405defa189&[PRODUCTJSON]
```

The Alamofire request I tried to execute is given below. The request fails with Bad Request Error (Status code 400)

```
    let cookies = "client=iOS; version=" + version + "; sellerId=" + sellerId + "; key=" + sellerKey


    let manager = Manager.sharedInstance
    manager.session.configuration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = [
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "Cookie": cookies
    ]

    Alamofire.request(.POST, ServerConfig.ADD_PRODUCT_URL, parameters: productJSON, encoding: .JSON, headers: nil)
        .responseJSON(completionHandler: { responseRequest, responseResponse, responseResult in
            print(responseRequest!.URL)
            print(responseResponse)
            print(responseResult)
       })
```

Please note that the Product Json does not include the client ID. I still have to figure out a way to include them both as parameters in the HTTP POST request.

Answer (score 2):

@godlike's answer is good, however you need to separate the postString parameters with ampersands not semicolons:

```
postString = "client=iOS&version=" + version + "&sellerId=" + sellerId + "&key=" + sellerKey
```

That worked for me.

Also, depending on where your input is coming from, you may want to consider encoding your variables to escape special characters.  If they are coming from a user's input you could do something like this:

```
let encodedUserMessage = userMessage.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .alphanumerics)
```

I would have just commented on @godlike's answer but I don't have enough reputation.  Hopefully that helps someone else out as I have just spent ages trying to figure out how to pass multiple parameters in.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I am doing my post requests:

```
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://blahblah.com/api/v1/products/saveDraft")!)
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
var postString: String?
postString = "client=iOS; version=" + version + "; sellerId=" + sellerId + "; key=" + sellerKey
request.HTTPBody = postString!.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
            data, response, error in

            if error != nil {
                print("error=\(error)")
                print("ERROR")
            }

//DO something
```